# Ubuntu default backup not working: duplicity-full.20220307T133808Z.vol3.difftar.gz

Tags: hard-drive, backup, deja-dup

My first time doing a backup with the default backup app for Ubuntu 20.04 -it is not described anywhere, and there is no tutorial or description either - but it seems is the Deja-Dup app.
I have a SSD drive for the OS, a mechanical 2TB drive for files. The goal is to backup to a external 2TB mechanical HD.

PROBLEM:
After a day long backup I get a list of .GZ files, which total lots less size-space than what I am trying to copy. I was expecting mirror copy of the folders I want to copy.

QUESTIONS:

1. Is this list of .gz files what I am supposed to get as a backup?
2. Does this software compares at each schedules backup and only updates new files?
3. How do I recognize a folder from the backup when needed if all have the same name?
4. If the answer to 1 is yes, is there a way -or a different software -  to do a simple folder to folder backup from HD to HD that does daily updates without copying the whole thing every time but compares?

Any help will be much appreciated  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the title of your question claims that it is "not working". Perhaps your expectations were incorrect.

1. The .gz files are compressed so that your backup takes less room than the original in most cases.
2. By default yes, it does incremental backups for three months, then takes another full backup
3. You use the same app, terminal commands, or file manager addons to restore files
4. You could probably set up something with rsync but I don't think there is anything that does this out of the box